# How to click an element giving error "Element is not clickable at point" with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click "See all teams" in this page "https://useinsider.com/careers/" with selenium but no matter what I try I get the "Element is not clickable at point" error. I am trying to do this in a larger project that is a part of POM structure, I am posting a highly simplified version of the code. I should mention my original code contains, necessary wait commands. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
# import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
  

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

  
# get geeksforgeeks.org
driver.get("https://useinsider.com/careers/")
path = '//*[@id="career-find-our-calling"]/div/div/a'
# get  element 
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path)
cookie = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#wt-cli-accept-all-btn')

  

cookie.click()

element.click()
```

I get this error

ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (600, 2489)
(Session info: chrome=112.0.5615.137)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is a permanent overlay of element on the desired element.
Check the below options.

**OPTION1:** Using Javascript as below

Change below line:

```
#driver.execute_script(element)
element.click()
```

To:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
#element.click()
```

**OPTION2:** Using Keyboard events as below:
Change this:

```
element.click()
```

To:

```
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

You would need below import:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I shared the wrong code. I am trying to do without execute_script, but in the end any method would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the updated answer. Permanent overlay of `div` element is probably causing Selenium to not click on the desired element. You have limited options as mentioned in my answer. Choose whichever best fits you.

Comment: That did it!. You should share this solution in every question regarding this error. Thanks a lot.